# Format ggmap legend without exponents / scientific notation

Tags: r, ggmap

I am new to R and `ggmap`. I would appreciate any tips on how to tidy up my legend and get rid of the exponents. Kind regards.

```
map2 <- ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(data = mapfilter, 
             aes(x = long, y = lat,
                 colour = YP_REV,
                 size = YP_REV,
                 darken = 0.3, 
                 alpha = 0.8)) + 
  scale_colour_gradient(low = 'red', high = 'green')
```

[image: 1]

Comment: How about a complete example? No idea where mapfilter comes from.

Comment: You can probably get rid of the exponents with `options(scipen=100)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing ggplot legend unit scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882072/changing-ggplot-legend-unit-scale)